# Why cout is not working in the friend function that overloads the operator << which is an istream operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, cout, istream

Why `cout` is not working inside a function that overloads the istream operator of C++(`>>`)?What should I do to make it work?

In the line: `cout >> "Enter x and y: "` shows an error?

Why?
How can I fix it?

This is the code to `overload >>`  and `operator <<`

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class myClass
{
    int x,y;
public:
    myClass(int a,int b)
    {
        x=a;y=b;
    }
    friend istream &operator>>(istream &in, myClass &ob);
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, myClass ob);
};
istream &operator>>(istream &in,myClass &ob)
{
    cout >> "Enter x and y: ";
    in >> ob.x;
    in >> ob.y;
    return in;
}
ostream &operator<<(ostream &out,myClass ob)
{
    out << ob.x << " " << ob.y << endl;
}
int main()
{
    myClass ob(10,20);
    cout << ob;
    cin >> ob;
    cout << ob;
}
```

Comment: When asking questions about errors, always include the actual errors you get. Copy-paste them (as text) into the question, in full and complete. Then add comments in the code to show where the errors happen. Also please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: `cout` is an output stream, so supports `<<` but not `>>`.   You are using `>>` which is invalid.    Voting to close, as this is essentially a typo (fix two characters).   Additionally, it is NOT a good idea to place output operations in the implementation of an `operator>>()` - reading from one stream should be independent, as far as the streams are concerned, of writing to another stream.  Instead write the prompt BEFORE using the `operator>>()`.   If you want to prompt for input, write a separate function that prompts to one stream and reads from another.

Comment: The `>>` operator is not supposed to interact with the user in any way. Suppose that you wanted to read a bunch of objects from a file - do you really want your program to print a prompt every time it reads one of them?

Comment: Your overloading is irrelevant; you would encounter the same problem with `int main() { cout >> "Enter x and y: ";}`. Read about the [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Your error is that you are mixing up `<<` and `>>`, `cout>>"Enter x and y: ";` should be `cout << "Enter x and y: ";`

Also it's not good style to prompt the user in an overloaded `operator>>`. What if your `>>` was being used to read from a file? You wouldn't want to prompt the user then. So move `cout<<"Enter x and y: ";` to the main function where it belongs.

Like this

```
istream &operator>>(istream &in,myClass &ob)
{
    in>>ob.x;
    in>>ob.y;
    return in;
}

int main()
{
    myClass ob(10,20);
    cout<<ob;
    cout<<"Enter x and y: ";
    cin>>ob;
    cout<<ob;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this wont compile as it still contains `cout>>""`

Comment: @AlanBirtles Sorry, fixed.